# cmake "libcurl was built with SSL disabled, https: not supported!"

Tags: curl, cmake, suse

I'm trying to compile the project parquet-cpp:
https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp

When I make, this is the error I get:

```
[  1%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'arrow_ep'
-- downloading...
     src='https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/a8f8ba0cbcf5f596f042e90b7a208e7a0c3925b7.tar.gz'
     dst='/home/D070470/workspace/parquet-cpp/arrow_ep-prefix/src/a8f8ba0cbcf5f596f042e90b7a208e7a0c3925b7.tar.gz'
     timeout='none'
CMake Error at arrow_ep-stamp/download-arrow_ep.cmake:22 (message):
  error: downloading
  'https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/a8f8ba0cbcf5f596f042e90b7a208e7a0c3925b7.tar.gz'
  failed

    status_code: 1
    status_string: "unsupported protocol"
    log: libcurl was built with SSL disabled, https: not supported!

  unsupported protocol





CMakeFiles/arrow_ep.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'arrow_ep-prefix/src/arrow_ep-stamp/arrow_ep-download' failed
make[2]: *** [arrow_ep-prefix/src/arrow_ep-stamp/arrow_ep-download] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/arrow_ep.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/arrow_ep.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm running SUSE Linux release 12.1, `uname-r` gives `3.12.74-60.64.40-default`

I tried removing curl with `zypper remove curl`, but the error stays the same, which is surprising.

When I print `curl --version` I get

```
curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.37.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1i zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

which shows that curl in fact has the SSL feature.

The fact that cmake still run curl and gets an error when curl isn't even installed maybe indicates that cmake uses its own version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So cmake does use its own version of curl.

I had to download cmake sources here https://cmake.org/download/
and use `./bootstrap --system-curl`, `make` and `make install` to have a cmake version which uses the system curl. I also needed to install the package `libcurl-devel`.